# Problems with displaying JLabels one after the other with a delay

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, event-dispatch-thread

I have this code:

```
public class Bum extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JButton  button;

    JLabel[] labels;

    public Bum()
    {
        setTitle("Bum!");
        setLayout(null);

        button = new JButton();
        button.setBounds(10, 10, 190, 190);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        add(button);

        labels = new JLabel[10];
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            labels[i] = new JLabel("YES");
            labels[i].setBounds(200, 200 + i * 50, 100, 30);
            add(labels[i]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            labels[i].setText("NO");
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(400);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Bum bum = new Bum();
        bum.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        bum.setVisible(true);
        bum.setExtendedState(bum.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }
}
```

There is a button, which has an ActionListener. If I click the button, then I want to change all labels, but one after the other with small breaks between (there I use Thread.sleep(400)). This program is wrong, because it changes all the labels at the same time.

Comment: Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `Thread.sleep()`, you are just freezing the [`EDT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) *(event dispatch thread)*.

Use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead to schedule a future event to trigger.

From the Oracle website:

> Swing consists of three kinds of threads:
>
> - Initial threads, the threads that execute initial application code.
> - The event dispatch thread, where all event-handling code is executed. Most code that interacts with the Swing framework must also
>     execute on this thread.
> - Worker threads, also known as background threads, where time-consuming background tasks are executed.

Answer (score 1):

Swing is single threaded. By calling `Thread.sleep`, you're preventing the updates in the `EDT`. Use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead.